# Windows - Scheduled Task Completing but not running | Possible 'NET' command permission issue

Tags: service, permissions, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, acl

I've been working for hours on this one. 
I have a scheduled task that is set up to be run by a non-admin account.

**What is does:**

Start a service at a specific time everyday.

**Command:**

```
NET START <service>
```

**Configuration:**

- Runs everyday at 6 PM
- Run with highest privileges
- Non-administrative account has the following access levels

  - Remote Desktop User
  - Log on as Batch Job
  - Log on as Service
  - Access to start/stop the service in ACL
  - Read/execute access to CMD.exe and NET.exe
  - Access to start/stop the task scheduler service
  - Access to the tasks directory in C:\Windows\System32\Tasks

**The Problem:**

Scheduled task runs but does not start service as intended. When temporarily granted admin access to account, scheduled task executes as intended.

**Investigation Notes:**

- Interestingly, if the account itself remotes into the box it CAN start/stop the service manually.
- The scheduled task completes with no errors whatsoever (even in eventvwr) but the service itself does not start.
- When the account is given admin access, the scheduled task runs as expected.

I'm looking into the possibility that there might be additional permissions involved to be able to execute 'NET START' but I've had little luck finding any information on that.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Exact same problem and haven't been able to find a solution. I also tested using runas as the user, and the net stop/start commands work fine. But will not by the task. Logging the output of net command just says "System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied." I'm guessing some other privileges for the user have to be set somewhere. No idea what though.

Answer (score 0):

you must check : "execute with highest privileges" in the Generel Tab